# How to customize Spring Security UI adding fields

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have installed Spring Security UI. It is working with the default fields:

- username
- email
- password
- password2

I want to add more fields. For example:

- phoneNumber
- grailsIsCool

So I type:

```
grails s2ui-override register packageName
```

It creates an empty class which extends: *grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController*.

**Is the correct way to do it to copy&paste all the code of the extended class where the default fields appear together** (username, email, password and password2) **Then, adding the new fields after them?** (phoneNumber and grailsIsCool). Alain Perry followed this approach and posted is code here: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Using-spring-security-UI-with-customized-user-class-td2330737.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good question.

I started using Grails about 5 months ago, and one of the first things I did was to install Spring Security and Spring Security UI. I initially used the `RegisterController` provided by the plugin, however I ended up rewriting most of it.

The UI `RegisterController` contains a lot a business logic - I prefer to keep my controllers as dumb as possible, so I created a `RegistrationService` and moved the `RegisterController` code I needed there.

Another gotcha was the `RegisterController`'s use of the grails command object pattern. I ran into problems when I deployed my app to CloudFoundry and couldn't figure out why. I later read that other people had [experienced the same issue](http://asoftwareguy.com/tag/command-object/). Simple workaround, but it left me scratching my head for a while...

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

So, on to your actual question. I guess the approach I took when I needed to add fields and otherwise customise the way the plugin worked was to just write my own implementation.

You can override the default Spring Security UI `User`, `Role` and `UserRole` classes by adding this to `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.myapp.MyUser'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.myapp.MyUserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.myapp.MyRole'
```

If you need additional fields, just add them to your `User` domain class, you'll also need to add validation logic to the `RegisterController`'s `Command`s to deal with these additional fields.

As for pulling your `Command`s out as top level classes, I just keep mine in the same package as the controller. One thing to note is that since they're no longer inside your controller, they will need to have a `@grails.validation.Validateable` annotation added to them otherwise they won't have the various validation methods available to them at runtime.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you! So, if I get the `Incompatible object argument for function call error`, I should create two separate classes: `RegisterCommand` and `ResetPasswordCommand`. But where? On the other hand, I wrote to the plugin authors [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYUI-54)

Comment: Updated my answer with some more info about how to extend the default Spring Security UI User implementation.

Comment: I'm sure your answer will be very useful for a lot of people! And for me too :) But just to be sure, you have in the same package than `RegisterController.groovy`: `RegisterCommand.groovy` and `ResetPasswordCommand` (with @grails.validation.Validateable). If it OK for your, let's wait a couple of days for and answer of the plugin's author. I still have faith to a "magic" way to add fields...